# Comma doesn't separate parameters

Tags: javascript, php

Trying to set up a WhatsApp button with a custom message, I've created a script in JavaScript to do that and calling it `onclick`.

I've tried moving quotation marks around but nothing works, this might be a silly issue but I just started with coding and can't get this to work, been trying since yesterday.

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
function sendSms(number, title) {
    window.open('https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=' + number + '&text=' + 'hello' + title);
}
```

Here is my PHP code:

```
echo '<span class="ad-whatsapp" onclick="sendSms(\' '. $ad_wa .' , '. str_replace(" ", "%20", get_the_title()) . '\')"></span>';
```

It seems to be sending the whole content of the parenthesis as the number parameter instead of separating the 2.

Comment: Shouldn't you close the string before the comma and reopen it after? `'\' , \''`

Comment: I hope these are in two different files/blocks, since you can't mix PHP and javascript as it is here. Look in the source of the browser, and show us exactly what it shows there.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon i had no idea, now i know, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function sendSms(number, title) {
    window.open('https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=' + number + '&text=' + 'hello' + title);
}

echo '<span class="ad-whatsapp" onclick="sendSms(\' '. $ad_wa .'\' , \''. str_replace(" ", "%20", get_the_title()) . '\')">bb</span>';
```

Comment: Thank you! that worked! I had no idea i had to close and reopen, now i know.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this instead:

```
echo "<span class='ad-whatsapp' onclick=\"sendSms('".$ad_wa."' , '".str_replace(" ", "%20", $this->get_the_title())."')\">asdf</span>";
```

Comment: Backticks are not valid quotes in PHP programming, or javascript for that matter.

Comment: You're wrong, backticks are used as [execution operators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php) in PHP and they're used to create [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Template_literals) in JavaScript.

Comment: @LogicalBranch Ah, thanks for the correction. Still incorrect for this code, but I've learned something new!

Answer (score 0):

Try using this JavaScript:

```
function sendSms(number, title) {
  window.open(`https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=${number}&text=hello${title}`);
}
```

With this PHP:

```php
<?php
  $replaced = str_replace(" ", "%20", get_the_title());
  echo '<span class="ad-whatsapp" onclick="sendSms(\'' . $ad_wa . '\', \'' . $replaced . '\')">SEND</span>';
?>
```

Good luck.